# website mouse scroll not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, mouse

I am check template but google chrome not working mouse scroll how can solved this issue. please check page [click here](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/09-03-2017/agro_seed-demo_Free/426125152/web/index.html)

Comment: it works for me in Google Chrome

Comment: yes its worked well in chrome. check with updated browser.

Comment: Are you referring to the back to top button? If you are then this is because an add is appearing on chrome with `z-index:999999999999`, which is covering the button. Your back to top button only has `z-index:999`. If you are unable to change the z-index of the add then change the z-index of your back to top button to `z-index:9999999999999;`.